# Perl CGI script print (utf-8 encoded - japanese html) over http (apache httpd) getting truncated

Tags: perl, http, utf-8, character-encoding, cgi

Environment settings

OS : RHEL 6.6 (kernel 2.6.32) - x86_64

httpd : httpd-2.2.15-39

perl : 5.10.1-136

CGI API :

perl-CGI-3.15-136

perl-CGI-Session-4.35-6

I am using a static html page with Perl-CGI defined variables in the static html. This html is read in through perl, and then passed to a perl CGI script for eval.
Note:

While reading the static html, I am using UTF-8 encoding like

```
open( IN ,"<:encoding(UTF-8)", $file_path )
```

After reading the status HTML page, the output is passed back to the CGI script through a variable and then pressed in to eval to evaluate the variables.

Finally, the eval(uated) output from CGI is print which can be read through http daemon.
In the CGI script I am using

```
binmode(STDIN, ':encoding(UTF-8)');
binmode(STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)');
```

The static HTML looks something like this
[image: actual_html (static)]

When I check the output of print in the CGI script, I see the complete output as desired, like this
[image: cgi print data]

However on the Browser, the hidden input fields are getting truncated in an unwanted manner. Like this

[image: truncated html]

When I checked the wireshark output for the text/html, which is being printed back from the server to the browser, this is also getting truncated.
Like this
[image: wireshark scan]

- The HTML header has proper Content-Type and charset declaration.
- The same code is working fine with EN language
- The same code is working fine with zh(chinese) language as well.
- When the language is set to japanese in the browser, and we read from HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE that it is 'ja', than we print the japanese specific data.
- We are not using cgid module of apache.

Are we supposed to use some special encoding for japanese language??
Or it is a double encoding issue. I have tried removing the encoding when I am reading the static html file, however, that also did not help.

- The same code is working fine with RHEL 5.x (2.6.18-308), and perl-CGI-Session (4.42-2), perl (5.8.8-38) httpd (2.2.3-63), there was no perl-CGI in RHEL-5.x.

Comment: How very odd. Is the Content-Length (measured in bytes) correct?

Comment: @ikegami san : As seen in firebug (firefox) I dont see the Content-Length coming in Response Header. Should I be calculating it in the final variable that I am printing and adding it in the meta data of HTML?

Comment: No, It should be fine without one (though I'd expect apache to provide a chunked response in that case (which is not necessary either)).

Comment: @ikegami san : I checked the html size as reported in firebug (though Content-length is not available in header), but the size if 5.37KB. Thereafter, setting the Content-length in the header to 5600 as Content-length: 5600 in the header, the size of the page being loaded is not increasing. It is remaining at 5.37KB and not changing. Note: After setting Content-length in header, I can see the Content-length in reponse header of firebug.

Comment: No surprises there. I already said that wasn't the problem.

Comment: @ikegami san : I think this problem is not about japanese language et al. I updated my page to be a static one, which is read through a CGI script and do print. When I am doing through JP language in browser, even this kind of standard HTML is getting truncated. With EN language in browser, it not getting truncated. I tried this on a default linux box, different from production, the problem DID NOT OCCUR ON IT.

Comment: @ikegami san: <Continued from previous comment>.... When I checked the header of the response, between production machine and default linux box, the response in case of production machine was in HTTP 1.0, however, in default linux box (personal system) was HTTP 1.1. Also Transfer-encoding in case of linux box was chunked. Please note that I am accessing the production machine's http page over a proxy. The header from production machine has something like this : Via: 1.0 gateway1.abc.co.jp:8080 (squid/2.6.STABLE6). Does having a proxy in the middle the cause? Please suggest/help!

Comment: chunked is used when there's no Content-Length. It basically adds a bunch of small content lengths to the body. "There's 4096 bytes coming. There's 4096 bytes coming. There's 122 bytes coming. There's nothing else coming." Using Content-Length or chunked allows the same connection to be used for more than one request.

Comment: Having a proxy shouldn't cause a problem, but software has bugs. If you could sniff between the proxy and the server, it would tell you more.

Comment: @ikegami: Ok, I will try and see if I can sniff around the connection between proxy and server! :-(

Answer (score 0):

I kind of found the solution to the problem. In our code we used to add a data in the CGI::Session object, which had the language. In the following form

```
$session->param( KEY_SESSION_LANG, $code ).
```

Where $session is a CGI::Session object and KEY_SESSION_LANG is 'language' and $code is something that we get from HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE. When we see 'en' we used to set it as perl constant 'en', when we got 'ja' we used to set it as perl constant 'ja'.

When we used to form the session object we used to get a session file as (perl version RHEL 5.x (2.6.18-308) & perl-CGI-Session-4.42-2 ) for JA language we used to get the following in the cgi file

```
cat cgisess_e31c8d21af82b59fd064babc7ca25c01
$D = {'_SESSION_ID' => 'e31c8d21af82b59fd064babc7ca25c01','_SESSION_ETIME' => 6000,'language' => 'ja','permit' => 'yes','_SESSION_REMOTE_ADDR' => '192.168.101.1','_SESSION_CTIME' => 1441090386,'execute' => 'yes','_SESSION_ATIME' => 1441090387,'_SESSION_EXPIRE_LIST' => {}};*a = \undef;;$D
```

For perl CGI Session in RHEL 6.6 this is coming out to be

```
cat cgisess_e31c8d21af82b59fd064babc7ca25c01
$D = {'_SESSION_ID' => 'e31c8d21af82b59fd064babc7ca25c01','_SESSION_ETIME' => 6000,'language' => *a,'permit' => 'yes','_SESSION_REMOTE_ADDR' => '192.168.101.1','_SESSION_CTIME' => 1441090386,'execute' => 'yes','_SESSION_ATIME' => 1441090387,'_SESSION_EXPIRE_LIST' => {}};*a = \undef;;$D
```

language data for ja is becoming *a. The same is also reflected when we use perl dumper for getting in memory data.

I checked the /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/CGI/Session.pm and it had following information in it

```
=head1 A Warning about UTF8

Trying to use UTF8 in a program which uses CGI::Session has lead to problems. See RT#21981 and RT#28516.

In the first case the user tried "use encoding 'utf8';" in the program, and in the second case the user tried "$dbh->do(qq|set names 'utf8'|);".

Until this problem is understood and corrected, users are advised to avoid UTF8 in conjunction with CGI::Session.

For details, see: http://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=28516 (and ...id=21981).

=head1 TRANSLATIONS

This document is also available in Japanese.
```

Now when I used the perl dumper following things happened. I quote below from my offical analysis presented on our local development portal

- I think the problem is because of perl-CGI-Session OSS package, please see the analysis below.

Some inputs from the CGI session source code.

```
 ## Inputs ##
From the file /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/CGI/Session.pm 
## Following are the status of CGI session, set internally after modification to any of the parameters ##

sub STATUS_NEW      () { 1 }        # denotes session that's just created
sub STATUS_MODIFIED () { 2 }        # denotes session that needs synchronization
sub STATUS_DELETED  () { 4 }        # denotes session that needs deletion
sub STATUS_EXPIRED  () { 8 }        # denotes session that was expired.

--snip --

I::Session - persistent session data in CGI applications

=head1 SYNOPSIS

    # Object initialization:
    use CGI::Session;
    $session = new CGI::Session();

    $CGISESSID = $session->id();
```

1. We are setting the "language" parameter in the session object. (We create a CGI object, set cookie to it, to get sid, and through sid get the session object). For setting up the language parameter we do
   $session->param( 'language',  ); ---> language_value = en(english) or ja(japanese). When we have completed the printing of the HTML page in /opt/packageManager/pm_gui/cgi/status.cgi file, I checked the cgi session object it is as follows
2. For EN Language

Before executing session flush

```
[09/10/2015 16:13:41] [23722] <ERROR> status.cgi : 267 :
 $VAR1 = bless( {
                 '_STATUS' => 2,

                 '_DATA' => {
                              '_SESSION_ETIME' => 6000,
                              '_SESSION_ID' => '995d11334f2c39b95b3fdb86cecd9655',
                              'permit' => 'yes',
                              'language' => 'en',
```

Then after this when I flush the session as $session->flush() and check the session object it is

```
[09/10/2015 16:13:41] [23722] <ERROR> status.cgi : 270 : 
 $VAR1 = bless( {
                 '_STATUS' => 0,

                 '_DATA' => {
                              '_SESSION_ETIME' => 6000,
                              '_SESSION_ID' => '995d11334f2c39b95b3fdb86cecd9655',
                              'permit' => 'yes',
                              'language' => 'en',
```

**Inference 1: session status changed after doing flush. This is good, and should be done.**

3. For JP Language
   Before executing session flush

   [09/10/2015 16:14:54] [31910]  status.cgi : 267 : 
    $VAR1 = bless( {
                    '_STATUS' => 2,

   ```
                '_DATA' => {
                             '_SESSION_ID' => '1cd1b7860af4c71264f3969fe74e7a44',
                             '_SESSION_ETIME' => 6000,
                             'language' => *a
   ```

**Then after this, when I flush the session as $session->flush() and check the session object it is NOT THERE. SCRIPT CRASHES HERE IT SELF**

**Inference 2 : Doing flush with language JP, is terminating the session, and that is why the session gets destroyed. And that is why, ending data in response is truncated**

Due to the wrong value being set in memory, in session object, and then the implicit flush by CGI session is failing on the disk. Which results in termination of the session object, and in between termination of session, and and data loss of HTML.

I checked the actual code in sessions.pm file and it seems to be coming in from here

```
sub param {
my ($self, @args) = @_;
--snip--
# USAGE: $s->param($name, $value);
# USAGE: $s->param($name1 => $value1, $name2 => $value2 [,...]);
# DESC:  updates one or more **public** records using simple syntax
if ((@args % 2) == 0) {
    my $modified_cnt = 0;
    ARG_PAIR:
    while (my ($name, $val) = each %args) {
        if ( $name =~ m/^_SESSION_/) {
            carp "param(): attempt to write to private parameter";
            next ARG_PAIR;
        }
        $self->{_DATA}->{ $name } = $val; ----> HERE
        ++$modified_cnt;
    }
    $self->_set_status(STATUS_MODIFIED);
    return $modified_cnt;
}
```

As a solution, we stopped putting 'ja' value as a perl constant, but now are putting it as a string "ja" and it seems to be working fine now.